# Inject $uibModalInstance to a controllar not initiated by a $uibModal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-modal

I have these two views:

1) foo.html

```
  <p>Hello {{name}}</p>
```

2) foo-as-modal.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <ng-include src="'foo.html'"></ng-include>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
</div>
```

The controller for foo.html is `fooController`:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('fooController', ['$scope','$uibModalInstance', function($scope,$uibModalInstance) {

     $scope.name = "John"

     $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
     };
}]);
```

I need to inject `$uibModalInstance` to `fooController` for the `.dismiss` to work

That works great when I invoke `foo-as-modal.html` as a modal, ie:

```
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'foo-as-modal.html',
        controller: 'fooController',
        scope: $scope.$new(),
        size: 'lg'
    });
```

But it throws error when I invoke `foo.html` as a normal view (via `$routeProvider` and `ng-view` directive), ie:

```
    .when('/foo', {
        templateUrl: 'foo.html',
        controller: 'fooController'
    })
```

Error is:

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- fooController
```

And the view doesn't display "John" (because of the error)

How can I solve this? I really NEED to reuse `foo.html` and `fooController` as a modal and non-modal, because they have lots of stuff (I've simplified here)

---

EDIT:
Here is a plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/9rfHtE0PHXPhC5Kcyb7P

Comment: can you make PLUNKR for this?

Comment: Done. https://plnkr.co/edit/9rfHtE0PHXPhC5Kcyb7P

Comment: Just curious, what do you expect to see on `/palletsRows` page?

Comment: whoops... edited, it was supposed to say /foo. I'm supposed to see "Hello John"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well I solved this way:

1. Removed the injection `$uibModalInstance` from `fooController`
2. When invoking the modal, **I pass the modalInstance as a variable to the modal's scope:**

   ```
   var modalScope = $scope.$new();

   var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
       templateUrl: 'foo-as-modal.html',
       controller: 'fooController',
       scope: modalScope
   });

   modalScope.modalInstance = modalInstance;
   ```
3. Dismiss the modal with the scope variable:

   ```
   $scope.modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');  // instead of $uibModalInstance.dismiss(..)
   ```

Here is a fork of the original plunkr, with this solution: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZasHQhl6M5cCc9yaZTd5

Answer (score 5):

You can not use the same controller for a page view and for a modal window. At least, untill controller depends on `$uibModalInstance`.

`$uibModalInstance` can be injected only in modals.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to resolve `$uibModalInstance` in the route with null (or an empty string/or whatever you please) and inject it into the controller. If the html page isn't opened as a modal, you still have `$uibModalInstance`. If it's opened as a modal, `$uibModalInstance` is automatically injected.