# Angular unknown provider uibModalInstance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to open and close a modal in an angualarjs application.  I've finally got it open but now can not close it.  I'm getting the unknown provider error.  I thought I've injected ui.bootstrap correctly in my app.  I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Using angular 1.6.  My index file has the script of angularjs, ui-bootstrap.js and the ui-bootstrap-tpls scripts.  If I take the uibModalInstance out everything runs fine modal opens but I have no way of closing it.

Here is my module:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ui.router", "ngAnimate", "angular-loading-bar","ui.grid","ui.grid.selection","ui.bootstrap", "common.services"])
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
//state config excluded
});
```

Here is the begining of my controller :

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular
    .module("myApp")
    .controller("productListCtrl", productListCtrl);

productListCtrl.$inject = ["$filter", "$timeout", "$uibModal","$uibModalInstance", "productDataService"];

function productListCtrl($filter, $timeout, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance, productDataService) {
    var vm = this;
```

And here is the error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <-    $uibModalInstance <- productListCtrl
```

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$injector/unpr?p0=%24uibModalInstanceProvider%20%3C-%20%24uibModalInstance%20%3C-%20productListCtrl
    at http://localhost:54575/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12

Comment: update the post with your script references

Comment: This would answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/37768522/87972

Answer (score 3):

remove ng-controller from your html if you written in html. It will solve your problem

---

Comment: This did indeed work, but why does it work?